# ORDERBY, ignorar acentos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho uma coluna `name` que pertence ao model `Producer_BVU`, cujos os nomes são:

```
2M1J
A. Coelho
ÓRBITA
Bruno
```

Quando ordeno:

```
\App\Producer_BVU::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
```

O output fica:

```
ÓRBITA
2M1J
A. Coelho
Bruno
```

Existe alguma maneira, de preferência sem modificar configurações charset do mysql, de nesta query `orderby` os acentos sejam ignorados?

Cujo resultado desejado é:

```
2M1J
A. Coelho
Bruno
ÓRBITA
```

Pode ser com alguma função de laravel após a extração dos dados sem problema, não precisa de ser logo na chamada à base de dados, secalhar até prefiro.

As minhas configurações em config/database relativamente ao mysql:

```
...
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
...
```

Comment: Tenta colocar no arquivo `database.php` essas instruções em `mysql` - `'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',`

Comment: Editei com esses detalhes @DiegoSouza. Mas de prefêrencia não gostaria de mexer aqui

Comment: E gostaria de mexer onde? *Pode ser com alguma função de laravel após a extração dos dados...*. Fazer isso é fazer o Order By duas vezes porquê a primeira vez não funcionou direito...

Comment: O mesmo ocorre se executar a query diretamente? Tipo pelo phpmyadmin?

Comment: @HulaHula esse campo de ordernação `name` foi criado em qual `collation`?

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic, foi com `utf8_unicode_ci`, mas já consegui, adicionei em cada item da colection um slug, e depois ordeno por isso. Já me safei, mas pode colocar a resposta se souber outra alternativa

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de especificar `ASC`, porquê por padrão já é assim.
Só precisa especificar o `DESC`.

```
$collection = \App\Producer_BVU::orderBy('name')->get();
```

Função alternativa para ordenação:

```
$collection = $collection->sortBy('name');

$collection->values()->all();
```

Outro jeito é alterar as configurações do driver `mysql` em `database.php`, o que particularmente eu considero mais correto para não ter que ficar usando recursos desnecessários, como o acima.

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não resultou, o resultado é mesmo, quanto às configs da driver mysql eu tenho as mesma que colocou. Acho que vou criar uma coluna coluna com slug, para isto